# How do I use HTML Data- Attributes in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

**I have seen this question asked in Stack Overflow but I have been unable to understand the answers given.** Could someone please rewrite what I have the proper way so that I can just look at it and understand what you've done.

Currently I have this HTML link that opens a lightbox and displays an image.

```
 <li><a href="images/product/image1.png" data-lightbox="example-set"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a></li>
```

However, since moving it into rails it doesn't work and I am wondering how I would rewrite this so that it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= content_tag :li do %>
   <%= link_to fa_icon("eye"), "images/product/image1.png", data: { lightbox: "example-set" } %>
<% end %>
```

This is assuming you're using the [`font-awesome-rails`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem, which comes with the [`fa_icon`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers) helper.